# Left-Right distinction of navicular inInterpreter["AnatomicalStructure"] function

Tags: curated-data, interpreter, anatomy

I am playing with bone structure with Interpreter["AnatomicalStructure"] function. I noticed left-right distinction of navicular, one of the tarsal bones at the base of the foot, was not working correctly. For example,

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Interpreter["AnatomicalStructure"]["calcaneus"], Background -> Black]
```

shows both left and right calcaneus, and

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Interpreter["AnatomicalStructure"]["left calcaneus"],  Background -> Black]
```

shows only left calcaneus.

However, although

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Interpreter["AnatomicalStructure"]["navicular"],  Background -> Black]
```

shows both left and right navicular,

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Interpreter["AnatomicalStructure"]["left navicular"], Background -> Black]
```

gives an error

```
式 Failureはプリミティブ Graphics3Dまたは指示子でありません．
```

I systematically checked all the bones in the body (I am an anatomist) but only navicular shows this error. Does anyone know how to circumvent this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Takashi Miura

Comment: The entity "navicular bone of foot" doesn't seem to have a left or right variant. I think the data is missing. A lot of the data is missing, for example `EntityValue[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "NavicularBoneOfFoot"], "NearbyStructures"]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Does it mean there's no way to circumvent unless Wolfram research notice this problem and adds information? (Since all the other bones have the left and right variant, the problem must be a mistake, not the lack of information.)

Comment: I just reported this case to Wolfram Technical Support Inquiry.

Comment: I just have a reply from Wolfram Research. I can circumvent this problem by using "navicular bone of left foot" instead of "left navicular" in the Interpreter. I am not completely convinced why this form is required for this specific bone, but for the time being I can go forward.

Comment: I now use version 13.3, and the problem no longer exists.